# How do I get the name of a TemplateTypeParmType in Clang?

Tags: templates, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using Clang to print out some information about my AST.

For example:

```
template<typename T>
class Slices : public Fruit {
  T fruit;
  int numberOfSlices;
  public: 
    Slices(T fruit, int numberOfSlices)
      : fruit(fruit), numberOfSlices(numberOfSlices) {
    }
    std::string getName() {
      return "Sliced " + fruit.getName();
    }
    int getNumberOfSlices() {
      return numberOfSlices;
    }
};
```

Should print something like:

```
template<typename T>
Slices
  Fields: 
    T fruit;
    int numberOfSlices
  Methods: 
...
```

I have written a visitor that hits a `TemplateTypeParmType` node at `T` in `T fruit`.

However, this node doesn't seem to have any identifiers attached to it. These are both `null`:

```
x->getDecl()
x->getIdentifier()
```

How do I extract the templated-name (here `T`) from this node?

Answer (score 2):

If you also have the `QualType` for that type (you can get it from the `FieldDecl` for every field, etc.), you can just call `getAsString()` on that. If not, you can create one with no qualifiers, i.e.

```
auto name = clang::QualType(type, 0).getAsString();
```

Of course the qualifier information (such as `const`) will then be missing. Make sure the type you have is not a canonical type (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#canonical-types), otherwise you'll just get a name like `type-parameter-0-0`.

I haven't found a way to get the decl or the identifier, but if you're willing to step through the clang code with a debugger, you can probably find where the `getAsString` method gets this information from.